# Some JList actions not being executed when ActionEvent is run via another method..? - Java

Tags: java, swing, button, netbeans, actionevent

So I have a button that is supposed to add a new user (whose name is taken from another class) to a list after being pressed. When I press the button by manually clicking on it after building and running, it works fine. The thing is that when I call the ActionEvent method **through another method, it outputs my System.out.println text but doesnt add any new entries to the list.**

Any suggestions?

Here's the code that is called in a button press (the line marked by an "<--" is the one that only seems to work if I manually press the button) :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        listModel.insertElementAt(name, index); // <--
        System.out.println("finished running action");
    }
```

Here's a more complete version of my code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("ran action");

        addAuthor();
        System.out.println("authornamefinalfunc name: " + name);

        //Reset the text field.
        employeeName.requestFocusInWindow();
        //employeeName.setText("");

        //Select the new item and make it visible.
        list.setSelectedIndex(index);
        list.ensureIndexIsVisible(index);
        System.out.println("ran action final");
    }
    private void addAuthor()
    {
        String name = Global.s;

        int index = list.getSelectedIndex(); //get selected index
        if (index == -1) { //no selection, so insert at beginning
            index = 0;
        } else {           //add after the selected item
            index++;
        }

        listModel.insertElementAt(name, index);

    }
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question with a working code sample. Please post your code as an [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Okay! ill change it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `addAuthor` method always being called on the event dispatch thread? `JList` (and everything in Swing) is **not** synchronized or thread safe so any Swing related modifications/actions **must** take place on that thread. Since the `addAuthor` method interacts with Swing components, it must **never** be called from any thread other than that one. This goes for any other method you have in that class (except possibly a `main` method if it's well written).

If you need to call `addAuthor`, or any other method that directly interacts with Swing components, from a thread that's not the event dispatch thread, use something like this to call the method (this assumes your Swing form is named "myUI"):

```
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
    addAuthor();
  }
});
```

You can also use `invokeLater` if you want to run the code and not wait for it to finish.

If you're not sure what threads code is running from, use these rules of thumb:

1. Any code that is in your `main` method, or called by your `main` method (no matter how many levels deep), is run by the "main" thread.

   - For example, your `main` method calls `foo()`, which in turn calls `bar()`, which in turn calls `foobar()`. All of the code in all of these methods is run by the `main` thread.
2. If you manually create a new Thread, for example with something like, `new Thread(...).start()`, that code, and the code in all methods called by it, are run from this thread.
3. All Listener code invoked by the UI (for example your `ActionListener` above when you press the button) is called by code on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Code run on the Event Dispatch Thread is the **only** code that can safely interact with Swing components. Methods with code that interacts with Swing components (like your `ActionListener` and your `addAuthor` methods) therefore must only be called from code running in the EDT.

If you want invoke the methods from any other thread (1 and 2 above), you need to use the method I've shown you above, since you can't do it directly.

Comment: If I put that in the actionPerformed method I get an error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Cannot call invokeAndWait from the event dispatcher thread

Comment: On the other hand, when I invoke the actionPerformed method via another method the code just seems to skip past it...

Comment: @user3749591: You're not supposed to put this code in the `ActionPerformed` method. The `ActionPerformed` method is already executed on the event dispatch thread when it is invoked by a Swing component. This code is supposed to go in the other method (the one where you call `ActionPerformed` but it doesn't seem to work).

Comment: @user3749591: All components and methods in Swing forms **must** be accessed only while in the event dispatch thread or you will have problems like the one you're facing.

Comment: @user3749591: Just post your code for the other method and I'll fix it for you.

Comment: @user3749591: ...but you really need to learn how threads are handled in Swing or things will never work right.

Comment: @user3749591: Cool! I updated my answer to hopefully make things more clear.