# Make Swing operations immediate

Tags: java, swing, time-wait

I have a method in Swing to hide and show some buttons, called `setScreen(int stage)`, which will hide or not certain buttons depending on the `stage` parameter. I want to call the method, then wait a few seconds and then call it again, like in this code:

```
... //Here stage has been assigned to some value

setScreen(stage);

if (stage != STAGE_TWO) {
  sleep(WAIT_TIME * 1000);
  stage = WELCOME;
  setScreen(stage);
}
```

The code for `setScreen(int stage)` is something like this:

```
void setScreen(int stage) {
    switch (stage) {
        case WELCOME:
            screen.infoLabel.setText("Welcome!");
            screen.startButton.setVisible(true);
            break;

        case STAGE_TWO:
            screen.infoLabel.setText("We are in stage two!");
            screen.startButton.setVisible(false);
            break;
    }

    screen.validate();
}
```

Where screen is an instantiation of a class extending JFrame.

The problem here is that the first `setScreen(stage)` is never displayed, since the thread goes to sleep before the changes have been commited. I have tried substituting the sleep for a while loop checking the time of the system, but the effect is the same.

**EDIT: ** I have found in a recommended StackOverflow thread some information on Swing Timer that may be useful. I'll work with it and upload any useful advances I make.

Comment: Swing Timer or a SwingUtils.invokeLater call

Comment: Yep. I probably covered what you need here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270226

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sleeping event dispatch thread. Don't do it and use:

```
javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(WAIT_TIME * 1000, new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (stage != STAGE_TWO) {
            stage = WELCOME;
            setScreen(stage);
        }
    }
});
timer.start();
```

The if condition may be for entire timer as per your requirement

Comment: Yes, the solution I ended up implementing is very similar to this one. Thank you.